# When I activated the Woow gallery plugin in WordPress, I received a fatal error

Tags: wordpress, class, plugins

When I try to activate the Woow Gallery plugin in my WordPress admin, this error appears.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "WoowGallery\Widgets" not found in C:\laragon\www\nilsabbass\wp-includes\class-wp-widget-factory.php:62 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\nilsabbass\wp-includes\widgets.php(115): WP_Widget_Factory->register('WoowGallery\Wid...') #1 C:\laragon\www\nilsabbass\wp-content\plugins\woowgallery\class-woowgallery.php(85): register_widget('WoowGallery\Wid...') #2 C:\laragon\www\nilsabbass\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(324): WoowGallery\WoowGallery->widgets('') #3 C:\laragon\www\nilsabbass\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #4 C:\laragon\www\nilsabbass\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #5 C:\laragon\www\nilsabbass\wp-includes\widgets.php(1858): do_action('widgets_init') #6 C:\laragon\www\nilsabbass\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(324): wp_widgets_init('') #7 C:\laragon\www\nilsabbass\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #8 C:\laragon\www\nilsabbass\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #9 C:\laragon\www\nilsabbass\wp-settings.php(643): do_action('init') #10 C:\laragon\www\nilsabbass\wp-config.php(103): require_once('C:\laragon\www\...') #11 C:\laragon\www\nilsabbass\wp-load.php(50): require_once('C:\laragon\www\...') #12 C:\laragon\www\nilsabbass\wp-admin\admin.php(34): require_once('C:\laragon\www\...') #13 C:\laragon\www\nilsabbass\wp-admin\plugins.php(10): require_once('C:\laragon\www\...') #14 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\nilsabbass\wp-includes\class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 62
There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

I tried deactivating and reinstalling the plugin, but it doesn't work, and uploading the plugin also doesn't work.